# "It's not the fall that kills you . . ." The capabilities of this kinetic shield

Tags: science-based, physics, electromagnetism

---

### Kinetic shields

From Dune's <s>Handwavium</s> I mean Holtzman-shields to NGE's AT-fields. It's a common practice to make knife fighting/D.E.Ws viable wit a magical shield, that counters any other attack types, this time I created one that nerfs the railguns a bit...

The key to this was [Israfel](https://youtu.be/83Q-mu-wrK8?t=56) from Neon Genesis Evangelion, from a standpoint, tough, this time, we're not interested in that.
[image]

### How it works

In short, this shield steals the energy from a kinetic projectile, with the help of neodymium magnets (blue) and conductors, (preferably, graphene)(orange)  through Faraday's Law of induction and the Lorentz force. I wrote in the super primitive schematics a few parameters to use. Also, the magnets are flux pinned to the object we need to protect and that object is levitated, when a hit strikes, enabling the shield to dissipate the force over the whole body (so, Gs and hitting the wall still can kill us), and there's also a flexible framework that keeps the magnets in place and it can break in a controlled manner when overstrained, wrapping the shield piece around the target (but we also ignore the framework, because it makes things even more complicated).

### Other Information

- For the sake of simplicity, let's assume, that these small
  nanomagnets, conductors are indestructible.
- For this experiment, we gonna use Average Joe (alias, John Doe), who can only withstand the Gs that a trained pilot could withstand in a G-suit.
- The nanoconductors have the same dimension, as the nanomagnets.

---

**Under these specifications, how thick would a force field need to be to stop a 1kg projectile that travels at the 99% of the speed of light?**

Comment: What is the rest mass of the projectile?

Comment: @JoeKissling 1kg.

Comment: Oops I must have missed it. My bad.

Comment: 1kg at 99% c is Ke measured in tens of megatons. Related [xkcd](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/)

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt Uh... guess the Average Joe doesn't have to do anything (as long as he's in a planet's atmosphere), the projectile destroys itself.

Comment: As well as anything within a mile of the shooter.

Comment: **99% of the speed of light** <- have you considered the implications? Can't happen.

Comment: @AndreiROM Actually, the scene was supposed to be in vacum.

Comment: @redactedredacted - doesn't matter. Light speed is not achievable. I won't say it's _basic_ physics, but it is a widely known fact.

Comment: @AndreiROM .99 c isn't light speed. The energy required to accelerate an object to that speed would be prohibitively expensive but it would be technically possible. For instance we've accelerated protons to 0.99999999 c in the Large Hadron Collider.

Comment: @sphennings - You mention protons, but those are individual particles, not a chunk of metal. It makes a big difference.

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/20/

Answer (score 2):

1kg at .99 C = it doesn't matter if pressure is spread over entire body or not. Doesn't matter at all. Just too much energy. 5.4$\times$ 10<sup>17</sup> J is a lot: approximately equal to the energy output 132 megatons of TNT.

So your guy can survive 5 g for some time. Let's say his mass is 100kg. So he can soak up 500 newtons (1 newton=1 joule/m<sup>2</sup>). But where does it take us?

Can't do relativistic calculations right now, but it seem that if all energy is supposed to end up as kinetic energy of Joe + missile, he is now flying at ⅓ c. That's kinda lot. Even if I'm mistaken by a huge factor, such shield is not practical, would need to reach really far away to accelerate him slow enough, far in terms of light minutes at best. Oh, and he would end up kicked out of the Solar System.

Tool used: https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/vCalc/Kinetic+Energy+(Relativistic)